# How to get the list of versions from an array after the specific version using Node JS Code?

Tags: node.js, optimization

I have an array with the list of stacks with versions eg `v4.5.3` ,

```
[ '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.6.0 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.4 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.3 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.2 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.1 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.0 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.6 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux v4.4.5 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux v4.4.4 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.3 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.2 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.1 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.0 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.3.0 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.2 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.1 running Node.js',
      '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.0 running Node.js']
```

I want to get the next latest versions after `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.3 running Node.js` that is

```
'64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.6.0 running Node.js',
'64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.4 running Node.js'
```

Approach 1 : What i did is i looped this array and finded the string `"64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.3 running Node.js"` and after that whatever elements where there i pushed to an new array was that the right approach ??

Approach 2 : I can use split of each element and i can find the `v4.6.0` but the problem is there is no guratee that these versions will be in the same position.

what is the best approach to do this in Node JS ?

Comment: is the list already sorted by decending version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you can use a regex to get the version.

```
const myVersions = versions.map((str) => {
    let match = str.match(/v\d+.\d+.\d+/)[0];
    let temp = match.split('');
    temp.shift();
    match = temp.join('');
    return {
        semver: match,
        text: str
    };
});
```

This will return versions as an array of objects with fields semever like `4.0.2` and text like `'64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.0.2 running Node.js'`.

**Secondly** you can write a compare function to sort according to the version numbers and get the desired output or you can use the `compare-versions` library for sorting which is already specified in the other answer.

```
function myCompareFunc(v1, v2) {
    let [major1, minor1, patch1] = v1.semver.split('.').map(Number);
    let [major2, minor2, patch2] = v2.semver.split('.').map(Number);
    if (major1 > major2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (major2 > major1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (minor1 > minor2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (minor2 > minor1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (patch1 > patch2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (patch2 > patch1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

myVersions.sort(myCompareFunc);
console.log(myVersions.map(ver=>ver.text));
```

**DEMO**

```js
const versions = ['64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.6.0 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.4 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.3 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.6 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.2 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.0 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux v4.4.5 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.3 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.2 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.1 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux v4.4.4 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.0 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.3.0 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.5.1 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.2 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.1 running Node.js',
    '64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v4.2.0 running Node.js'];

const myVersions = versions.map((str) => {
    let match = str.match(/v\d+.\d+.\d+/)[0];
    let temp = match.split('');
    temp.shift();
    match = temp.join('');
    return {
        semver: match,
        text: str
    };
});


function myCompareFunc(v1, v2) {
    let [major1, minor1, patch1] = v1.semver.split('.').map(Number);
    let [major2, minor2, patch2] = v2.semver.split('.').map(Number);
    if (major1 > major2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (major2 > major1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (minor1 > minor2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (minor2 > minor1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (patch1 > patch2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (patch2 > patch1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

myVersions.sort(myCompareFunc);
console.log(myVersions.map(ver=>ver.text));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said in "Approach 2", I'm supposing you already obtained an array containing only the version numbers. You could use [compare-versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compare-versions).

This library is able to:

> Compare semver version strings to find greater, equal or lesser.

```
    var compareVersions = require('compare-versions');

    var versions = [
      '1.5.19',
      '1.2.3',
      '1.5.5'
    ]
    var sorted = versions.sort(compareVersions);
    /*
    [
      '1.2.3',
      '1.5.5',
      '1.5.19'
    ]
    */
```